# Should I use a LinearLayout with repeated background or a SVG ImageView to fill a whole row?

Tags: android, android-imageview, android-background, androidsvg

## Linked questions

The below questions couldn't finally solve my problem, described below.

- [Android: Is it possible to repeat an (SVG!) drawable inside an ImageView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55581786/android-is-it-possible-to-repeat-an-svg-drawable-inside-an-imageview)
- [Android: Keep ratio for a full-width and undefined height ImageView in a ConstraintLayout?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55562638/android-keep-ratio-for-a-full-width-and-undefined-height-imageview-in-a-constra)
- [Showing a full-width ImageView containing a SVG distorts it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55561747/showing-a-full-width-imageview-containing-a-svg-distorts-it?noredirect=1&lq=1)

## Context

I use a `ConstraintLayout`. My aim is to show **an SVG image** which contains a button:

1. Its width is 100% the screen's width - it must be repeated
2. Its height is defined to be the space between the bottom side of a widget and the bottom side of the button - it must be repeated

## The problem

Each time I tried to show this image, either the drawable was badly scaled, badly cropped or blurred.

An exemple is:

[image]

It should look like this:

[image]

## Many tests

1. I have tried to use an `ImageView` with the attribute `src`: I used every scale type, with and without the attribute that allows to set a custom ratio
2. I have tried to use an `ImageView` with a background instead of `src`
3. I have tried to use a `RelativeLayout` with a background drawable file that is repeated: so I didn't use an SVG image but its JPEG version, and even this way has resulted in bad results
4. Nota for 3.: I'd really want to use an SVG image instead of a bitmap one, because it will be resolutions-compliant.

## My question

So, given all these explanations (*cf.:* part Context) and given the above illustrations, how would you proceed to show this image?

Answer (score 0):

use java code

```
    ColorDrawable colorDrawable = new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#888888")); // bg color
    Drawable vDrawable = AppCompatResources.getDrawable(this, R.drawable.ic_vector_star); // vector drawable
    if (vDrawable != null) {
        Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(vDrawable.getIntrinsicWidth(), vDrawable.getIntrinsicHeight(),
                Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
        vDrawable.setBounds(0, 0, canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight());
        vDrawable.draw(canvas);
        BitmapDrawable bitmapDrawable = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), bitmap);
        bitmapDrawable.setTileModeXY(Shader.TileMode.REPEAT, Shader.TileMode.REPEAT); // set repeat

        LayerDrawable drawable = new LayerDrawable(new Drawable[]{colorDrawable, bitmapDrawable});
        findViewById(R.id.frameLayout).setBackground(drawable);
    }
```

[image: example]